# org.apache.spark.sql.Row cannot be resolved in Spark 2.0 Preview

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am already using Spark 1.6.1 and now evaluating Spark 2.0 Preview, but I am not able to find org.apache.spark.sql.Row.

This is required as, I am migrating my DataFrame code in 1.6.1 to 2.0-preview. Am I missing something over here? My maven dependency is pasted below

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-preview</version>
         <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>C://spark-2.0.0-preview-bin-hadoop2.7//jars//spark-core_2.11-2.0.0-preview.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-preview</version>
         <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>C://spark-2.0.0-preview-bin-hadoop2.7//jars//spark-sql_2.11-2.0.0-preview.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 7):

in spark v2.0.0 Row has moved to another jar file ,
add this to your maven dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-catalyst_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-preview</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>C://spark-2.0.0-preview-bin-hadoop2.7//spark-catalyst_2.11-2.0.0-preview.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it works for me.
Moved from Spark 1.6.1 to 2.0
For Maven,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-tags_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-preview</version>
</dependency>
```

For SBT ,

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-tags_2.11" % "2.0.0-preview"
```

For Gradle,

```
compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-tags_2.11', version: '2.0.0-preview'
```